# Add JSON format cookie to the response - Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, cookies, gson

Am trying to add cookie to response using java servlet in JSON format. I see cookie is being created with extra double quotes and slashes. I've tried using GSON library to parse json string.

```
HashMap<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
        jsonMap.put("name", "someName");
    Cookie myJsonCookie = new Cookie("cookieName", new Gson().toJson(jsonMap));
        myJsonCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        myJsonCookie.setSecure(true);
        myJsonCookie.setPath("/");
        myJsonCookie.setMaxAge(60*60);
        response.addCookie(myJsonCookie);
```

[Following code is adding cookie as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DIOp.png)

How to escape quotes and slashes?

Comment: For future reference the standard way is to base64 encode the cookie but without padding - that way if you switch app servers you don't have to find the magic flag in that server. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531740/encoding-java-cookie-value) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As am using Tomcat 7 app server. Adding property solved the issue.
`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true`